# Two different layouts using fancyhdr

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I would like to set two different layouts (namely headers) for my document. The document is two column dictionary. First part will be introduction with chapters and sections and the second part the dictionary itself where the headers are made from the first and the last headword on the page. 
I dont know how to set the first layout with chapter in header and than how to change it to different layout. Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{book}
\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=2cm, left=2cm, right=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[icelandic, czech, english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x, utf8]{inputenc}
\newcommand{\entry}[2]{\hangpara{2em}{1}\textsf{\textbf{#1}}\ #2\markboth{#1}{#1}\par}\nopagebreak[4]
\pagestyle{fancy}
\newcommand*{\dictchar}[1]{\centerline{\LARGE\textbf{#1}}\par}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\textsf{\textbf{\rightmark\ -- \leftmark}}}
\fancyhead[LO,RE]{\textsf{\textbf{\thepage}}}
\usepackage{fix2col}
\begin{document}\maketitle
\thispagestyle{plain}
\chapter*{1. First chapter}
\section*{1.1 First section}
...
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please reduce your code to a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use the command `\fancypagestyle` for defining your header layouts. The first argument is the name of your layout, the second argument contains the commands you would like to apply. Afterwards you can choose any of those custom layouts by `\pagestyle` and `\thispagestyle`.

Example:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancypagestyle{basicstyle}{%
  \fancyhf{}
  \fancyhead[LE,RO]{\rightmark}
  \fancyhead[LO,RE]{\leftmark}
  \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}}
\fancypagestyle{otherstyle}{%
  \fancyhf{}
  \fancyhead[C]{header}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}}
\pagestyle{basicstyle}
\begin{document}
\chapter{One}
\section{First section}
\thispagestyle{otherstyle}
\clearpage
text
\end{document}
```

Comment: Problem is now that there comes to the first layout the headwords (that should appear in the second layout) - probably from `\newcommand{\entry}[2]{\hangpara{2em}{1}\textsf{\textbf{#1}}\ #2\markboth{#1}{#1}\par}\nopagebreak[4]` command. Should I place this command to the propriet fancypagestyle?

Comment: @chejnik I suggest, post a new question with your current code (compilable small demo example) and your `\fancypagestyle` settings.