# Display All Section Marks on the Page's Header

Tags: header-footer, titlesec

Typing a document with package `titlesec, pagestyles` can easily mark **first** and **last** section title in the page header. But How to display ***all*** section marks that appears in the page to the page's header? TKS!

HERE is MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}

\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}
\newpagestyle{mapage}{%
    \setheadrule{1pt}
    \sethead[\color{red}\bfseries\toptitlemarks\sectiontitle--\bottitlemarks\sectiontitle][][\thepage/page header]
    {\thepage/page header}{}{\color{red}\bfseries\toptitlemarks\sectiontitle--\bottitlemarks\sectiontitle}%odd head
    \setfoot[][][]%even foot
    {}{\thepage}{}
}

\usepackage{blindtext,multicol,xcolor}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{mapage}

\begin{multicols}{3}
\section{AA}
\blindtext
\section{BB}
\blindtext
\section{CC}
\blindtext
\section{DD}
\blindtext
\section{EE}
\blindtext
\section{FF}
\section{GG}
\section{HH}
\blindtext
\section{II}
\section{JJ}
\section{KK}
\section{LL}
\end{multicols}

\begin{multicols}{3}
    \section{MM}
    \section{NN}
    \section{OO}
    \blindtext
    \section{PP}
    \section{QQ}
    \section{RR}
    \section{SS}
    \section{TT}
    \section{UU}
    \blindtext
    \section{VV}
    \section{WW}
    \section{XX}
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution using `fancyhdr` because I am more familiar with that than with `titlesec`s header stuff. I don't even know if my solution is easy to transform to `titlesec`.

My solution is to put all the section titles ina LaTeX3 `seq` (sequence), and to put the index of the section title in the `seq` in the mark. In the header I then extract those section titles between the first mark and the last mark of the page from this `seq`. Of course this is done with some LaTeX3 programming.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{extramarks}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\seq_new:N \section_list
\int_new:N \section_index

\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{%
  \seq_gput_right:Nn \section_list {#1}
  \int_gincr:N \section_index
  \markright{\int_use:N \section_index}
}

\fancyhead[LO,RE]{\thepage/page~header}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{
  \color{red}\bfseries
  \seq_map_indexed_inline:Nn \section_list {
    \int_compare:nNnF {##1} < {\firstrightmark} {
        \int_compare:nNnTF {##1} < {\lastrightmark}
          {##2--}
          {
            \int_compare:nNnT {##1} = {\lastrightmark}
              {##2}
          }
      }
    }
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\usepackage{blindtext,multicol,xcolor}
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{3}
\section{AA}
\blindtext
\section{BB}
\blindtext
\section{CC}
\blindtext
\section{DD}
\blindtext
\section{EE}
\blindtext
\section{FF}
\section{GG}
\section{HH}
\blindtext
\section{II}
\section{JJ}
\section{KK}
\section{LL}
\end{multicols}

\begin{multicols}{3}
    \section{MM}
    \section{NN}
    \section{OO}
    \blindtext
    \section{PP}
    \section{QQ}
    \section{RR}
    \section{SS}
    \section{TT}
    \section{UU}
    \blindtext
    \section{VV}
    \section{WW}
    \section{XX}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: That's what I want! Many thanks for your answer! When I use three different fancy styles, I need to define a fancy style `\fancypagestyle{bodystyle}{\fancyhf{}\fancyhead……}` as in [this example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32878/two-different-layouts-using-fancyhdr). But the error info shows that `! Illegal parameter number in definition of \temp@a.` and `You meant to type ## instead of #, right?` How to avoid this error? Thanks again for your help!